# How Redirect Urls That Blocked By Isp Provider in browser?

Tags: javascript, php, json, linux, firefox

do you have any idea how redirect urls that browser shows "unable to connect" with javascript?

i tried so many time by changing dns but it didn't work.

for example:

https://facebook.com/

Redirect To:

https://example.com/www.facebook.com/

Comment: Use a SOCKS tunnel to bypass the content filter: https://ma.ttias.be/socks-proxy-linux-ssh-bypass-content-filters/

Comment: Not sure it's possible with Javascript alone. My first idea was to use a userscript to check if the loaded page is equivalent to the `error` page, but the userscript doesn't seem to load at all if the document entirely fails to load. An extension might be able to do it, though.

Comment: SOCKS will bypass all of traffic, i don't want this. In Extension I'm Sure Javascript  wont load. what about save urls before pressing Enter key?